# Kernel module shows me 8 processors instead of 4 for Intel i5-2500K

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cpu, hardware

My question mostly about hardware, specifically the [Intel i5-2500K CPU](https://ark.intel.com/en/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz) which Intel describes as having

> # of Cores 4
>    # of Threads 4

Linux shows me 4 processors:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep ^processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
```

Nevertheless, I've written a little kernel module that shows me 8 processors:

```
$ cat show_cpus_mod.c 
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>

#define CLASS_NAME "show_cpus_mod"

#define dbg( format, arg... )  do { if ( debug ) pr_info( CLASS_NAME ": %s: " format , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg ); } while ( 0 )
#define err( format, arg... )  pr_err(  CLASS_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define info( format, arg... ) pr_info( CLASS_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define warn( format, arg... ) pr_warn( CLASS_NAME ": " format, ## arg )

MODULE_DESCRIPTION( "shows all cpus" );
MODULE_VERSION( "0.1" );
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
MODULE_AUTHOR( "author <e@mail.mail>" );

static int show_cpus_mod_init( void ) {
        int cpu;
        info( "Start loading module show_cpus_mod.\n" );
        for_each_possible_cpu( cpu ) {
                info( "cpu = %d\n", cpu );
        }
        return 0;
}

static void show_cpus_mod_exit( void ) {
        info( "Module show_cpus_mod unloaded\n" );
}

module_init( show_cpus_mod_init );
module_exit( show_cpus_mod_exit );
```

Building:

```
$ cat Makefile 
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
TARGET = show_cpus_mod
obj-m := $(TARGET).o

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order
        @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
        @rm -fR .tmp*
        @rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

Inserting:

```
# make
# cp show_cpus_mod.ko /lib/modules/4.14.0-kali3-amd64/
# depmod
# modprobe show_cpus_mod
```

syslog:

```
localhost kernel: [67596.578805] show_cpus_mod: Start loading module show_cpus_mod.
localhost kernel: [67596.578808] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 0
localhost kernel: [67596.578809] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 1
localhost kernel: [67596.578810] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 2
localhost kernel: [67596.578811] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 3
localhost kernel: [67596.578811] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 4
localhost kernel: [67596.578812] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 5
localhost kernel: [67596.578812] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 6
localhost kernel: [67596.578813] show_cpus_mod: cpu = 7
localhost kernel: [67607.725738] show_cpus_mod: Module show_cpus_mod unloaded
```

What am I missing in Intel's description? **Why 8?** Or what is wrong with my kernel module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `for_each_online_cpu` or `for_each_present_cpu` instead of `for_each_possible_cpu`. That will limit the output to CPUs which are really online or present, respectively.

Comment: yeah, thanx. `possible` is something wrong...